# Cannot unmarshal field with non string value from xml

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling

I have such xml response

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <Hubl xmlns="http://com.zap.oldschool/">
      <Mubl>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="si"?&gt;&lt;Zap&gt;&lt;Zap ZapId="literal"</Mubl>
    </Hubl>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And my java object is ok when Im unmarshling it except field 'Mubl', getting null for it.
I want to get ZapId value somehow

My pojo for 'mubl'

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Mubl")
public class Mubl {
    @XmlElement(name = "Mubl")
    private String mubl;

    public String getMubl() {
        return mubl;
    }

    public void setMubl(String mubl) {
        this.mubl = mubl;
    }
}
```

Will appreciate suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

1. `private String mubl;` (in `Mubl` class) is a `@XmlValue` and not `@XmlElement`
2. In your xml you have xmlns - it means that u specified namespace. So, If namespace is used, you have to use it in annotations too (what's more, XML elements inherit parent's namespace if they don't declare one). So, your implementation tries to get hubl and mubl with namespace = "" when the namespace of these elements is "http://com.zap.oldschool/". That's why, you have to add namespace parameter to annotations @XmlRootElement and @XmlElementin Huble class.

Comment: Ok, maybe this: I think that `mubl` is a root = class and property of this class = value of this XML element... so, let's replace `@XmlElement` with `@XmlValue`.

Comment: still having null

Comment: @XmlRootElement(name = "Hubl")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Hubl {
    @XmlElement(name = "Mubl")
    private Mubl mubl;

    public Mubl getMubl() {
        return mubl;
    }

    public void setMubl(Mubl mubl) {
        this.mabl = mabl;
    }
}

Comment: add `namespace = "http://com.zap.oldschool/"` to `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement` in Hubl.class. (+ previous changes). It works for me

Comment: can you be more specific?)

Comment: in your xml you have xmlns - it means that u specified namespace. So, If namespace is used, you have to use it in annotations too (what's more, XML elements inherit parent's namespace if they don't declare one). So, your implementation tries to get `hubl` and `mubl` with namespace = `""` when the namespace of these elements is `"http://com.zap.oldschool/"`. That's why, you have to add `namespace` parameter to annotations `@XmlRootElement` and `@XmlElement`in `Huble` class.

Comment: thanks man, can you post it inn separate answer and I will receive it as correct one?